# Subscribed element is null if property is called

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Using angularfire2 to subscribe on the auth object. Running this code works just fine and the authData object is printed to the console:

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(authData => {
  console.log(authData);
});
```

Output: `Object {auth: X, uid: "xXj8n6KnZcNDU8rBH....", provider: 3, google: Gi}`

But when I want to print only one of its properties, it will say the object is null:

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(authData => {
  console.log(authData);
  console.log(authData.uid);
});
```

Error: `Cannot read property 'uid' of null`

How can I access the property of `authData`?

Comment: try this `console.log(JSON.parse(authData).uid)` , also try checking the type of your object `authData`

Comment: Adding that line gives me an error `Argument of type FirebaseAuthState is not assignable to parameter of type string`

Comment: that is different problem i think.

Comment: The only way that what you've described could occur is that, in the second snippet, you are not signed in. In that case, the `auth` observable will emit `null`. If you are signed in, `auth` will emit a state object that contains the the `uid` property. I'm voting to close this, as the question doesn't contain a [mcve].